# Defining range of values as NoData using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, nodata, erase

I have a raster from GEBCO with pixel values ranging from -5888 to 5485 m. I only want to analyze the Bathymetry so I am looking for a way to assign noData values to all values >0. I also have a polygon of the coastline so if there is some way to do a clip outside of a polygon that would work also. I am working in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the SAGA raster calculator with the formula:

```
ifelse(a>0, 0/0, a)
```

Use the default "Output Data Type" (`4 byte floating point number`)